# Prove whether this language is (partially) decidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability

I'm currently working on a few turing machine exercises and I can't understand how I can prove whether the below is at least partially decidable:

$\{M \mid L(M) = \{x \mid |x| = 10\}\;\}$ where $|x|$ is the length of word $x$

Can anyone explain to me what the above statement actually means and an idea of how to go about it please?

Comment: This statement means the set of TM indexes (natural numbers under some fixed encoding) where each TM accepts a language containing all strings of length $10$.

Comment: Usually, positive answers are justified by crafting a semidecider. Negative answers often are justified by Rice-Shapiro (if your course cover that) or explicit reduction from some known non-semidecidable problem (e.g. the complement of the halting problem).

Comment: Another way to explain it, "$\{x  \mid |x| = 10\}$ is the (finite) set of strings of length $10$. $L(M)$ represents the language accepted by $M$. $A = \{ M \mid ...\mbox{ someproperty }... \}$ represents the set  of Turing machines that satisfy "someproperty". Your question is: given a Turing machine $M$ does there exist an algorithm that is able to halt if $M$ accepts exactly the strings of length $10$ and rejects *all* the strings longer or shorter than $10$? If yes then $A$ is partially decidable.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, particularly @Vor as the notation was confusing me. I am now assuming that this is provable using the halting problem.

Comment: @Ponsietta: or you can directly apply the Rice theorem (if you already studied it)

Comment: @Vor yes we did the Rice theorem, however doesn't that just prove undecidability rather than partial decidability?

Comment: ... yes, it's undecidable :-)

Comment: aa that explains it :P